# How to include list environment in "titlepage"

Tags: lists, titles

I've bee writing my own class for meeting notes, and I want to have an `fbox` with everyone who has attended the meeting, preferably in a list (`itemize` or my own custom list). Is there a way to do this in the title, so that the list is always rendered with the command `\maketitle`? I've seen plenty of variables defined in making your own "title page" (in quotes, because it won't be a page on its own), but no environments/lists.

MWE of what I'm after:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
  {\Huge Meeting}\\
  \today\\
  Start time: XX:XX\\
  End time: XX:XX
\end{minipage}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
  \textbf{Attendees}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Member one
    \item Member two
    \item etc.
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
%% End of the stuff I want the \maketitle command to create.
\end{document}
```

I want to know if it's possible to get the Attendee's included the same way title usually is e.g.

```
\title{Meeting}
\begin{attendees}
\item Member one
\item Member two
\item etc.
\end{attendees}
\starttime{XX:XX}
\endtime{XX:XX}
\maketitle
```

Any other ways of achieving the same thing in a class are welcome!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Are you aware of Jim Hefferon's [minutes in less than hours](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/hefferon/hefferon.pdf)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\stime#1{\gdef\@stime{#1}}
\def\etime#1{\gdef\@etime{#1}}
\def\attlist#1{\gdef\@attlist{#1}}

\def\@stime{\@latex@error{No start time given}\@ehc}
\def\@etime{\@latex@error{No end time given}\@ehc}
\def\@attlist{\@latex@error{No attendees list given}\@ehc}

\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
\par\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  {\Huge\@title\par\smallskip}
  \@date\\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  Start time: & \@stime\\
  End time: & \@etime
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \textbf{Attendees}
  \begin{itemize}
  \@for\temp@a:=\@attlist\do
    {\item \temp@a}
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}\par\bigskip%
}
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
\if@twocolumn
  \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
\else
  \@maketitle%
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\stime{08:00}
\etime{10:00}
\attlist{Member one, Member two, Member three, Member four}
\title{Meeting}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

You provide the information using `\stime` (for the start time), `\etime` (for the end time) and `\attlist` (a comma separated list of all the attendees) in a fasion similar to the standard `\author`, `\title` commands. If those commands are not provided an error is generated and an informative text is shown in the output console and written in the .log file. Support for a two-column document has been also provided.

The relevant code is between `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` since the example is a `.tex` file; those commands are *not* to be used inside a `.sty` or `.cls` file.

Comment: This is nearly to the letter the same I had when I realized you already answered. One should maybe add support for a twocolumn document, though, too. (Although - that probably depends one the expected use case in the end...)

Comment: @cgnieder great minds think alike? ;-) You're right; I'll add support for a two column document in some minutes.

Comment: At least they both had had a look into `latex.ltx` and `article.cls` before and knew where to start :)

Comment: @cgnieder support for two-column documents added.

Comment: Fantastic! Better than I'd imagined.